# Rotate background procedural texture

Tags: rendering, texturing

I want to put a procedural texture in the background of my image. I set the "World" color to a texture I like, and I would like to change the angle of this texture. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is edit the *World* nodes. Go to the *Node Editor* and click the globe icon:

[image]

Makes sure you check the *Use Nodes* checkbox as well.

Now add an *Input > Texture Coordinate* and a *Vector > Mapping* node and connect them as shown:

[image]

Now the three *rotation* values will adjust the orientation of the texture.