# How can I create a star field background that rotates in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How can I create a 'world' in cycles that is a star field, and rotates with one of the objects in the scene?

The effect I'm going for is that of a time-lapse of the night sky. The rotating object is going to be the sun lamp, so the stars move realistically with the night and day. (The scene is set on an asteroid, so the stars will be visible throughout.)

I could rotate everything else in the scene, but this would quickly become a real pain, having everything rotating all the time while trying to animate it.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/stars-background-in-cycles

The only thing not listed there is a way to get the star field to rotate. For that, I suggest looking into **Drivers** and the **Mapping** node.

Comment: To rotate read this links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41748/rotate-background-procedural-texture and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47833/how-do-i-rotate-an-environment-texture/47834#47834